# Evaluate delayed evaluation when it is called in Python

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

I have a program in which a variable is coming from either an explicit value or a delayed evaluation. I would like them to 'respond' in the same way when they're called.

Minimum working example:

```
import random


class DelayedEvaluation:

    def __init__(self, function):
        assert callable(function), "Input argument {} is not callable and can thus not be a delayed evaluation.".format(function)
        self.__delayed_evaluation = function
        self.__class__ = type(self.__delayed_evaluation())  # Does not work!

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__delayed_evaluation()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.__delayed_evaluation())


delayed_evaluation = DelayedEvaluation(lambda: 42)
print(delayed_evaluation)  # Works.
print(delayed_evaluation + 1)  # Does not work!
delayed_evaluation + 1  # Does not work!


for i in range(100):
    value = random.choice((DelayedEvaluation(lambda: 42), 43))
    print(value + 1)  # Does not work when 'value' comes from 'DelayedEvaluation'.
```

In the above I have tried to achieve this by introducing the class `DelayedEvaluation` and set its type to the type of the value of the function when evaluated.

I would like `DelayedEvaluation(lambda: 42)` to 'respond' the same way as `43`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: just as side info. 
As far as I know `__repr__` should normally return a string and not an int.

Though this might work in many cases it might perhaps break in some other cases.

So it's probably safer (more paranoid) to `return str(self.__delayed_evaluation())`

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not work is rather simple.

the delayed evaluation is triggered by the fact, that print wants a string representation of the object and calls therefore the function `__repr__` or `__str__` of the instance of DelayedEvaluation.

if you call `delayed_evaluation + 1` you do not trigger a call to `__repr__` or `__str__`.

What you could do is implement the '+' operator

```
   def __add__(self,other):
         return self.__delayed_evaluation() + other
```

If it should work for other operators you had to implement all the operators that you'd want to be treated.